# ORA-00936: missing expression when reading from database with dotConnect driver and oracle database

Tags: c#, dotconnect

I am using dotConnect driver for connecting to oracle database but i always get this error when i want to use parameters: ORA-00936: missing expression

CODE:

```
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT stevilka_dokumenta from zmpt_dokumenti_po where status = @status"; ;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", OracleDbType.VarChar, "1");

                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string stevilkaDokumenta = reader.GetString("stevilka_dokumenta");
                    }
                }
```

Error is here:

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

why i get ORA-00936: missing expression? How must i declare input parameters?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

just try changing `@status` to `:status`.

Comment: According to the documentation, the synax in the question is correct, but your answer solved the problem: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/db2/docs/Parameters.html

Comment: @Frederik it's for Db2 provider

Answer (score 0):

Also, to those still having issues, make sure you don't include a Semicolon at the end...

Comment: Something along the lines of unrecognized character.  It was just a gotcha that I figured I throw out there.