# how can I use handle Verbatim String Literals?

Tags: c#, string, oracle, string-literals, verbatim

I have below oracleCommand and like to change below but having error...doesn't except my +item+ and + txtSrcUserID.Text.ToUpper() + . in the oracleCommand. How can I add them to my command?

**Original**

```
foreach (string Items in listBox39.Items)
                    {
                        using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE ( REPLACE ( dbms_metadata.get_ddl ('PROCEDURE', 'HELL_'), '""USER1"".'),'^\s+', NULL, 1, 0, 'm') FROM dual", conn1))
                        {

                        }
                    }
```

**I like to make similar to below**

```
foreach (string Items in listBox39.Items)
                        {
                            using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE ( REPLACE ( dbms_metadata.get_ddl ('PROCEDURE', '+ Items +'), '"" + txtSrcUserID.Text.ToUpper() + "".'),'^\s+', NULL, 1, 0, 'm') FROM dual", conn1))
                            {

                            }
                        }
```

Comment: You're trying to have a SQL injection vulnerability.  Use parameters.

Comment: how to use parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (string Items in listBox39.Items)
{
    using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE ( REPLACE ( dbms_metadata.get_ddl ('PROCEDURE', '" + Items + @"'), '""" + txtSrcUserID.Text.ToUpper() + @""".'),'^\s+', NULL, 1, 0, 'm') FROM dual", conn1))
    {

    }
}
```

But as @SLaks suggested in his comment, better to use parameters:

[OracleCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters.aspx)

[OracleCommand SQL Parameters Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048910/oraclecommand-sql-parameters-binding)

Comment: not works:( I have ""USER1"" but your answer has only one quotation " + txtSrcUserID.Text.ToUpper() + "

Comment: I have updated the answer, this depends that your txtSrcUserID.Text contents is only: USER1, I still encourage you to use the links in my answer to use parameters.