# dbms_output.Put_line in c# Dapper

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

I need return a variable oracle to C#, however I use Dapper, so exist a way to receive a output by dapper?

I tried like this

```
ORACLE    ...
            ,NULL                                                               /*CLIENTE_GRUPO_CPF*/
            ,'P'                                                                /*LOTE_PRODUCAO_PEDIDO*/
            ,'N'                                                                /*LIBERACAO_COMERCIAL*/
            ,NULL                                                               /*USUARIO_LIB_COMERCIAL*/
            ,NULL                                                               /*DATA_LIB_COMERCIAL*/
            ,NULL                                                               /*HORA_LIB_COMERCIAL*/
            ,'L'                                                                );
    COMMIT;
    dbms_output.put_line(var_zi_controle_id);
    END ;


C#  
var id = conn.QueryFirstOrDefault<int>(sql);
```

but this way the answer is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dbms_output.put_line(var_zi_controle_id);` to Output a variable is incorrect, this would not work with programming languages / database driver like ODP.Net, this is for console printing and verification.

`Dapper` consist of set of extension methods which extends `IDbConnection` interface of ADO.Net, internally for Oracle you would fill in `ODP.Net - OracleConnection` object, now when you check the ODP.Net guide for calling any of the PL SQL Stored procedures, you have following options:

1. Bind a Output or Return parameter and fill the parameter in the PL SQL procedure. Using Dapper, you need `DynamicParameter` for binding parameters beside Input like Output / Return
2. Other option is way you are currently trying, you are expecting `Select` statement to return the value as integer, so what you need is `Select var_zi_controle_id` in the procedure, which will come as a QueryResult, but still you would need a Type T, which contains an integer value, here you would get a Type / class with one integer property `var_zi_controle_id`. `Query<T>` though returns `IEnumerable<T>`

My Preferred way would be adding the Output parameter, assign in the Stored Procedureand retrieve value, check the links underneath for good reference. A simple example would be:

```
 var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
 dynamicParameters.Add("var_zi_controle_id",0,DbType.Int32,ParameterDirection.Output)
```

`Parameter Direction` options `InputOutput` and `ReturnValue` can also be used, but `ReturnValue` needs explicit return value from the procedure

// Execute the Stored Procedure

```
conn.Execute(@"ProcedureName", dynamicParameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

// Fetch O/p Parameter Value from `dynamicParameters`

```
var id = dynamicParameters.Get<int>("var_zi_controle_id");
```

Its important that Output parameter `var_zi_controle_id`, which bind to the stored procedure is set, before the call returns, for value to be fetched

[OracleCommand SQL Parameters Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048910/oraclecommand-sql-parameters-binding)

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleCommandClass.htm#ODPNT458

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleParameterClass.htm#ODPNT1722