# ORA-O1036: Illegal variable name/number

Tags: c#, oracle, desktop, ora-01036

There are alot of posts related to this question but no one work for my case. I am using oracle database with C# on visual studio

```
void addUser()
{
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        string query ="INSERT INTO users (user_id, f_name, hash, acc_type, cell_no, country, state, city, zip, address, email, img) VALUES ('" +                         Convert.ToString(username) + "','" + Convert.ToString(f_name) + "','" + password + "','" + acc_type + "','" + contactno + "','" + country + "','" + state + "','" + city + "','" + zip + "','" + address + "','" + email + "',imgByte)";
        OracleCommand sc = new OracleCommand(query, usersdb);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("imgByte", imgByte);
        try
        {
            usersdb.Open();
            sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            usersdb.Close();
            lblSignupError.Visible = true;
            lblSignupError.Text = "Signed up successfully. You can login now.";

            Clear();
            LoginNow();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            if (usersdb.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                usersdb.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

Here is the code for Signup to add user in DB but this error comes

> ***Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException' in System.Data.OracleClient.dll System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException
>   (0x80131938): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
>
> at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle
>   errorHandle, Int32 rc)    at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameterBinding.Bind(OciStatementHandle
>   statementHandle, NativeBuffer parameterBuffer, OracleConnection
>   connection, Boolean& mustRelease, SafeHandle& handleToBind)    at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle
>   statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid,
>   OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList&
>   resultParameterOrdinals)    at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal(Boolean
>   needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor)    at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   StopNShop.SignUpForm.addUser() in E:\Visual Studio
>   Projects\StopNShop\StopNShop\SignUpForm.cs:line 402***

Comment: _hash_ is a reserved keyword in Oracle

Comment: In addition to DavidG's comment... It will help because most likely is the cause of the problem

Comment: Namespace `System.Data.OracleClient` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for ages, you should not use it anymore.

Comment: Try `Debug.WriteLine(query);` - most likely you will see the error. Anyway, use bind variables for all values not just `imgByte`.

Comment: what to use instead of Namespace System.Data.OracleClient?

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using parameters for **all** your input values; not only will it be more readable, but it will prevent [SQL injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15) attacks.

In answer to your question, oracle parameters should be prefixed with a colon i.e. `:imgByte`.

See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11048965/8126362