# 'ORA-00917: missing comma' In insert Query in Oracle From .Net Project

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core

I have been trying to run an insert query into oracle table from .Net project. The query is as follows:

```
var commandTextgpt = $"INSERT INTO tl_order " +
                  $"(ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_GROSS_AMOUNT, ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DESCRIPTION, ORDER_TYPE_LKP_ID, REQUIRED_BY_DATE, CUSTOMER_MASTER_ID, " +
                  $"DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, ORDER_NET_AMOUNT, TAX_AMOUNT, USER_ID, EMAIL_ADDRESS, PAYMENT_TERMS, LOCATION_ID, CUSTOMER_SIGNATURE_IMAGE_URL, ACTIVE_FLAG, " +
                  $"PAYMENT_METHOD, MOBILE_ORDER_ID, TMX_STATUS, DST_STATUS, CUSTOMER_MASTER_CODE, LOCATION_CODE, ITRANSACTION_NUM) " +
                  $"VALUES (" +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_ID"]}, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_DATE"]}, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_GROSS_AMOUNT"]}, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_NUMBER"]}, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_DESCRIPTION"]}, " +
                  $"NULL, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["REQUIRED_BY_DATE"]}, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["CUSTOMER_MASTER_ID"]}, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["DISCOUNT_AMOUNT"]}, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_NET_AMOUNT"]}, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["TAX_AMOUNT"]}, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["USER_ID"]}, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["EMAIL_ADDRESS"]}, " +
                  $"NULL, " +
                  $"NULL, " +
                  $"NULL, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ACTIVE_FLAG"]}, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["PAYMENT_METHOD"]}, " +
                  $"NULL, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["TMX_STATUS"]}, " +
                  $"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["DST_STATUS"]}, " +
                  $"NULL, " +
                  $"NULL, " +
                  $"NULL)";
```

the `orderDatafromDynastyTables` is a DataTable object getting data from an Mssql database its defination is as follows

```
var orderDatafromDynastyTables = FetchSQLQueryForDyastyData(sqlQuery, orderId, ordDate, 
ordShipDate, customerCode);
```

The following is the data I am getting in `orderDatafromDynastyTables`

```
ORDER_ID: 65121
ORDER_DATE: 2013-12-14 09:18:52.000
ORDER_GROSS_AMOUNT: 1023.6200
ORDER_NUMBER: ORD011805065121
ORDER_DESCRIPTION: NESTLE
ORDER_TYPE_LKP_ID: NULL
REQUIRED_BY_DATE: 2013-12-14 09:18:52.000
CUSTOMER_MASTER_ID: 100008
DISCOUNT_AMOUNT: 0.0000
ORDER_NET_AMOUNT: 1023.6200
TAX_AMOUNT: 0.0000
USER_ID: 103.53.46.250
EMAIL_ADDRESS: NULL
PAYMENT_TERMS: NULL
LOCATION_ID: NULL
CUSTOMER_SIGNATURE_IMAGE_URL: NULL
ACTIVE_FLAG: 1
PAYMENT_METHOD: Payments.CashOnDelivery
MOBILE_ORDER_ID: NULL
TMX_STATUS: READY
DST_STATUS: READY
CUSTOMER_MASTER_CODE: NULL
LOCATION_CODE: NULL
ITRANSACTION_NUM: NULL
```

I have listed down the column names and the respective values. Its just a single record as expected.

The following is a screenshot of my Oracle table

[image]

I have been trying to debug this with the help of ChatGpt and everything, but I still haven't found the issue. Help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please do not use concatenation to build SQL queries it makes them vulnerable to injections, use [parametrized queries](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/adonet-in-a/0596003617/ch04s04.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were really going to embed the values in the SQL statement like that then you would need to put quotes around string values and dates, e.g. instead of:

```
$"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_NUMBER"]}, " +
```

you could do:

```
$"'{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_NUMBER"]}', " +
```

And you shouldn't rely on implicit conversion of dates, so instead of:

```
$"{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_DATE"]}, " +
```

or

```
$"'{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_DATE"]}', " +
```

you could convert explicitly with a format mask, to a timestamp as you have fractional seconds:

```
$"to_timestamp('{orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_DATE"]}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), " +
```

(or add a `cast(... as date)` to be even more explicit; if the fraction seconds are always zero you could also use `to_date()`  and embed those in the format model as a fixed value.)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pHjHcIrG) with just the first four columns, showing the error without the quotes and success with quotes and explicit conversion.

**But don't do this at all.** It would be much better to use bind variables (as @MT0 has shown) rather than embedding values in a string like this - better for performance, and simpler to maintain, but also to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

**NEVER** build queries using template strings; that is how you introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities into your code.

Instead, use a [parameterised query and bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11048910/1509264):

```c#
var commandTextgpt = $"INSERT INTO tl_order " +
                  $"(ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_GROSS_AMOUNT, ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DESCRIPTION, ORDER_TYPE_LKP_ID, REQUIRED_BY_DATE, CUSTOMER_MASTER_ID, " +
                  $"DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, ORDER_NET_AMOUNT, TAX_AMOUNT, USER_ID, EMAIL_ADDRESS, PAYMENT_TERMS, LOCATION_ID, CUSTOMER_SIGNATURE_IMAGE_URL, ACTIVE_FLAG, " +
                  $"PAYMENT_METHOD, MOBILE_ORDER_ID, TMX_STATUS, DST_STATUS, CUSTOMER_MASTER_CODE, LOCATION_CODE, ITRANSACTION_NUM) " +
                  $"VALUES " +
                  $"(:ORDER_ID, :ORDER_DATE, :ORDER_GROSS_AMOUNT, :ORDER_NUMBER, :ORDER_DESCRIPTION, NULL, :REQUIRED_BY_DATE, :CUSTOMER_MASTER_ID, " +
                  $":DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, :ORDER_NET_AMOUNT, :TAX_AMOUNT, :USER_ID, :EMAIL_ADDRESS, NULL, NULL, NULL, :ACTIVE_FLAG, " +
                  $":PAYMENT_METHOD, NULL, :TMX_STATUS, :DST_STATUS, NULL, NULL, NULL)";


OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand(commandTextgpt, db);
using(var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql,con)
{
   OracleParameter[] parameters = new OracleParameter[] {
      new OracleParameter("ORDER_ID", orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_ID"]),
      new OracleParameter("ORDER_DATE", orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_DATE"]),
      new OracleParameter("ORDER_GROSS_AMOUNT", orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_GROSS_AMOUNT"]),
      new OracleParameter("ORDER_NUMBER", orderDatafromDynastyTables.Rows[0]["ORDER_NUMBER"]),
      // etc...
   };

   cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```